# NodeJS : Mongoose findByIdAndUpdate() returns null

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Consider the following code on NodeJS for updating a Document By id:

```
router.put('/:orderId', async(req, res) => {
    
    let update_orderId = req.params.orderId;
    let new_item = req.body.item;
    let new_item_desc = req.body.item_desc;
    let new_quantity = req.body.quantity;
    let new_unit_price =  req.body.unit_price;
    let new_total_cost = new_quantity * new_unit_price;
    let new_status = req.body.status;
    let new_priority = req.body.priority;

    await RequestPermissionOrderSchema.findByIdAndUpdate( update_orderId, {
            $set: {
                item: new_item,
                item_desc: new_item_desc,
                quantity: new_quantity,
                unit_price: new_unit_price,
                total_cost: new_total_cost,
                status: new_status,
                priority: new_priority,
                directOrder: false
            }
        },
        { new: true, useFindAndModify: false}, function (err, docs) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                res.send(err);
            } else {
                console.log("Updated Request Permission Order : ", docs);
                res.json(docs);
            }
        });
});
```

Everything is according to the latest documentation of Mongoose 5.10.9 and the schema also contains all the properties specified under  `$set: { ... }` . But when I execute, I get the output as follows ***in the console***:

```
updated Request Permission Order : null
```

I also make sure of whether the  `_id`  is available in the mongoDB database and that object ID is there. I can't seem to find what I did wrong. Really appreciate any help on this !


Also, note that I want to update by the  `_id`  auto-generated by MongoDB with each document.

Comment: is your document updating in mongodb ?

Comment: No, the document is not updated.

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the JSON object, remove the $set

```
 await RequestPermissionOrderSchema.findByIdAndUpdate( update_orderId, {
            $set: {     // REMOVE THIS $set
                item: new_item,
                item_desc: new_item_desc,
                quantity: new_quantity,
                unit_price: new_unit_price,
                total_cost: new_total_cost,
                status: new_status,
                priority: new_priority,
                directOrder: false
            }                 // REMOVE THIS ALSO
        },
```

Only the JSON object.

Comment: No luck with that as well. I tried something like: ```RequestPermissionOrderSchema.findByIdAndUpdate( update_orderId, req.body , ...``` but it did not work as well. I'm starting to think what my other options are for updating the specific document.